# Python is not saving a csv file, how to fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Here i just tested if it wanted to save in two different ways, 
but its not working the file is nowhere to be found on my pc

```
import csv

def writecsv(data):
    with open('CT_10-10-1.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerow(data)
    csvFile.close()

def write(data):
    csvFile = open('CT_10-10-1.csv', 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(data)

#writecsv('10')
write('10')
```

Comment: The file sould be near your script while you're not using a full path.

Comment: search on my entire pc for the file, but it didn't find it

Comment: Fyi both methods work. If there is no exception (i.e. permissions) it should be somewhere there.

Comment: think i found the issue, i was running it via the command line. but that doesn't work. still thx for help